# Remove "Bash Prompt Here" from context menu

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin

I uninstalled Cygwin, but I'm not able to remove "Bash Prompt Here" option from the windows context menu (right click).

I've tried these programs (http://www.thewindowsclub.com/remove-click-context-menu-items-editors), but none of them let me see this menu entry, and I'm not able to remove it...

Any idea about to remove it?

Comment: Consult the registry keys here: https://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/

Comment: `HKCU\*\shell` and `HKCU\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers` is where you want to be sniffing around.

Comment: @selbie I've just looked for something there, but nothing seems to be related to that menu entry. Here a screenshot: [https://ibb.co/edFXmF](https://ibb.co/edFXmF)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regedit. Look for cygwin in the register.
On my 64 bit installation I see:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cygwin64_bash
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cygwin64_bash
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\Background\Shell\cygwin64_bash
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\cygwin64_bash
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\cygwin64_bash
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\cygwin64_bash
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Drive\Background\Shell\cygwin64_bash
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Drive\shell\cygwin64_bash

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\XLaunch.cygwin
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\XLaunch.cygwin
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\cygwin64_bash
```